# Change values in list object

Tags: database, list, excel, vba

I am working with a list of bowling matches and want to update all matches for a specific week and a specific division.

By use of VBA, how do I change values in a column in a list for rows filtered for specific criteria on another column?

Comment: What have you done so far and what problems are you facing to achieve this, please publish your code and a sample of your data, so we can help you out. Otherwise your question seems like a order place for code writing and will get deleted.

Comment: I just want to know if there is a funktion that updates a table using qalifiers like SQL where clause. "where omg=7 and div="SE""

Answer (score 0):

Something like that might be possible, but it's extremely difficult to asses without looking at the data. In SQL you have a database with fields and items, Excel tables can hold the data in a similar fashion, yet again as in SQL you need to see the relationship between the fields and items, to asses what can be done.